# Registration form is not submitting

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

After trying multiple solutions from other stack overflows, I cannot seem to get my registration form to work in Django.

This is the registration form

```
  <h1>Register</h1>

    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}"></form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </div>
```

Below is the views.py
`

```
def register_page(request):
    form = CustomUserCreateForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('login')
    
    page = 'register'
    context={'page':page, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'login_register.html', context)
```

`

The forms.py
`

```
class CustomUserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

`

Its not throwing any error, rather just not submitting. I tried changing the input to button feature but it is still not working. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think saving the form instance doesn't actually make `user` an authenticatable User object

Try this

```
    if form.is_valid():
        #You are not doing anything to user, so no need to commit=False
        #user = form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        #Make sure user is an authenticated user object
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        #Handle no user as appropriate eg,
        #else:
        #    messages.error(request,'Well that didn't work')
```